# Using vectors in selectors

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

I want to create a custom selector for a button.

If the button isn't pressed a border like below should be displayed and the area inside the border should be transparent:

```
|‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾\
|         \
|         /
|________/
```

If the button is pressed the border and the area inside it should become light green.

I've tried to achieve it with the following selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:width="20dp"
            android:height="20dp"
            android:viewportWidth="100.0"
            android:viewportHeight="100.0">
        <path
            android:pathData="M 29.00,19.00
       C 29.00,19.00 60.00,19.00 60.00,19.00
         61.88,19.01 64.23,18.95 66.00,19.60
         69.90,21.03 78.62,30.62 82.00,34.00
         84.18,36.18 89.99,41.75 91.40,44.00
         95.12,49.94 89.79,54.78 86.05,59.00
         82.10,63.46 70.67,77.68 66.00,79.40
         64.06,80.12 61.09,80.00 59.00,80.00
         59.00,80.00 8.00,80.00 8.00,80.00
         -0.15,79.85 0.01,77.22 0.00,70.00
         0.00,70.00 0.00,35.00 0.00,35.00
         0.00,30.09 -1.23,23.82 2.31,20.02
         7.35,18.11 22.77,19.00 29.00,19.00 Z"
            android:fillColor="@color/button_pressed"
            />
    </vector>
</item>
<item android:state_pressed="false">
    <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:width="20dp"
            android:height="20dp"
            android:viewportWidth="100.0"
            android:viewportHeight="100.0">
        <path
            android:pathData="M 29.00,19.00
       C 29.00,19.00 60.00,19.00 60.00,19.00
         61.88,19.01 64.23,18.95 66.00,19.60
         69.90,21.03 78.62,30.62 82.00,34.00
         84.18,36.18 89.99,41.75 91.40,44.00
         95.12,49.94 89.79,54.78 86.05,59.00
         82.10,63.46 70.67,77.68 66.00,79.40
         64.06,80.12 61.09,80.00 59.00,80.00
         59.00,80.00 8.00,80.00 8.00,80.00
         -0.15,79.85 0.01,77.22 0.00,70.00
         0.00,70.00 0.00,35.00 0.00,35.00
         0.00,30.09 -1.23,23.82 2.31,20.02
         7.35,18.11 22.77,19.00 29.00,19.00 Z"
            android:strokeWidth="5"
            android:strokeColor="#484848"
            />
        </vector>
    </item>
</selector>
```

But it doesn't work as expected.
When the button isn't pressed the border isn't displayed, but if the button is pressed the border and the area inside it are displayed in different colors.

I tried to set the transparent background when the button wasn't pressed

```
android:fillColor="#80000000"
```

but it didn't help

I also tried to set

```
android:strokeWidth="0"
```

when the button was pressed, but it didn't help either.